# eclipse+hibernate - core exception on new hibernate xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

As the title, I'm trying to use the Hibernate framework, but I'm stuck at the first steps.
First of all, I've added the JBoss repository to Eclipse.
Then, I created a new Java project and a new class, named "User.java", with some private variables and all the getters and setters.
Then, after switch to Hibernate perspective, I've tried to create the "User.hbm.xml" file (right click on the project> New Hibernate XML mapping files). In the wizard, I selected my package (pervasive.com.gmail.tigerjack89.hibernate.orm), then my class (User.java), then reviewing the changes and finally clich "Finish".
However, the workspace error log generates the sequent Core Exception

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/Hibernate_test/pervasive/com/gmail/tigerjack/hibernate/orm' does not exist.
```

from Plug-in org.hibernate.console

This is the whole error stack trace

```
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/Hibernate_test/pervasive/com/gmail/tigerjack/hibernate/orm' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.create(File.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.corext.refactoring.nls.changes.CreateFileChange.perform(CreateFileChange.java:165)
    at org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.CompositeChange.perform(CompositeChange.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingPreviewPage.performFinish(NewHibernateMappingPreviewPage.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.performFinish(NewHibernateMappingFileWizard.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.actions.NewWizardShortcutAction.run(NewWizardShortcutAction.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4454)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3799)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3409)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Just surprised still someone is using .hbm.xml approach in age of annotation as well why it becomes require to add jboss jars. By the way about your error its coming because your resource files are not placing in proper location by your eclipse compiler just verify whether these are files are there under classes folder location.

Comment: @prashantthakre I don't want to use one approach or another, I'm still in the learning phase, so please give me a good tutorial on how to use annotations. I don't get the jboss jars part btw, what I've doing wrong?
About the error, I'm not sure what to do. Both `bin` and `src` folder have only the User source/class, nothing more. Also, there is no track in any place of hibernate or jboss jars.
http://i60.tinypic.com/24gvywk.png